# How to make mongodb verify that the error report points to the field name

Tags: mongodb, jsonschema

When I defined JsonSchema on the collection, I thought that the data was not valid, I could see which field was wrong, but the error I got was: `Document Failed Validation`.

Is there any way to see which field of the Document?

Comment: Not sure about what mongoDB can do, but as a last resort, you can copy & paste to any online validator, e.g.: https://jsonschema.dev/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version of mongoDB doesn't provide you with detaild JSON Schema errors. You cannot simply use another implementation of JSON Schema to determine the error because mongoDB uses a modified version from an old version of JSON Schema. You may want to file a support request with them.

Comment: already exists https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-20547 and is currently being worked on.

Comment: Great! to hear. you may find it interesting that JSON Schema draft `2019-09` has a standardised output, which can then be converted into error messages. You may consider using similar structure to end users to construct their own errors